# можно проверить через find введенную сроку в структуре?

Tags: c++, c, строки

Как-то так или нет?

```
string streets;
 
cout << "Введите улицу: ";
cin >> streets;
int n = 0;
 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{    
    if (streets.find(arr_Students[i].adress)) {
        n++;     
    }       
}
cout << "Количество студентов, живущих на указанном с клавиатуры улице:" << n;
```

Comment: когда я ввожу улицу n не считает

Comment: Какой тип у `arr_Students[i].adress`? Вам нужно искать улицу в адресе, а не наоборот (как сейчас).

Comment: char adress[40]

Comment: сделайте __минимальный компилируемый пример__, напишите какой результат вы получаете и какой ожидаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если и `arr_Students[i].adress`, и `streets` имеют тип `string`, то

```
if (arr_Students[i].adress.find(streets) != string::npos) 
{
    // Найдено
}
```

Но если `char[]` - то тот же `if`

```
strstr(arr_Students[i].adress,streets) != NULL
```

Если, скажем, `arr_Students[i].adress` - `chsr[]`, а `streets` - `string`

```
strstr(arr_Students[i].adress,streets.c_str()) != NULL
```

Comment: а если адрес char?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно искать улицу в адресе, а Вы ищите адрес в улице. Т.к. `arr_Students[i].adress` - это массив `char`, а не `string`, то нужно создать временную переменную типа `string`, в которую сохранить `arr_Students[i].adress`, а потом уже искать:

```
string streets;
 
cout << "Введите улицу: ";
cin >> streets;
int n = 0;

string tempAddress;
 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{   
    tempAddress = arr_Students[i].adress;
    if (tempAddress.find(street) != string::npos) {
        n++;     
    }       
}
cout << "Количество студентов, живущих на указанном с клавиатуры улице:" << n;
```